# A problem involving showing the existence of a particular ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis

I was working on a problem and I ended up needing to prove the existence of a $C^2$ function $\phi:(0,\infty)\to \mathbb{R}$ such that $\phi'(t)\geq0$ and given $p>2$ then $\phi$ satisfy:

$\bigg( \frac{4}{p-1} - \frac{1}{2p}\bigg)(\phi'(t))^2 + \phi'(t)(1-\frac{1}{2p}) +p-1\leq \frac{\phi''(t)}{2p}.$

But I have no ideia how to construct such function.

As the inequality seens to be fulfilled for a function that grows fast, I tried $\phi(t)=e^{f(t)}$, and then try to find a $f$ appropriated, but that didn't work .

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't exist.

Note that the general solution of the differential equation
$f'(t) = k f(t)^2$ is  $f(t) = 1/(c - k t)$. If $f(0) > 0$ (so $c > 0$)
and $k > 0$, this "blows up" to $+\infty$ at $t = c/k$.  Your $\phi'$ is supposed to satisfy $\phi' \ge 0$ (and if $\phi'(t) = 0$, $\phi''(t) \ge 2 p (p-1) > 0$ so $\phi'(t_1) > 0$ for $t_1 > t$).  But then $\phi''(t) > k \phi'(t)^2$ with $k = 2 p (4/(p-1)- 1/(2p)) > 0$.  We conclude that $\phi'$ is greater than the solution of $f' = k f^2$ with the same initial condition, and so it must also go to $+\infty$ at a finite $t$.

Comment: Thanks for the help Robert!!